# Is it possible to test if two sha2 hashes came from the same plain text?

Tags: php, cryptography, hash

The following are both SHA256 hashes of an empty string, generated with PHP's crypt function.

```
$5$fooooooooooooooo$Y6IVN.cYkABQ4h8dCR0zL/rJoRx09pwMoGaYST9HqDD
$5$baaaaaaaaaaaaaar$C84IKQdPMG8qvnnckGZsyBJWKHuaSD0tqcmyueHI0GA
```

Each was generated with a different 16 bytes of salt present in the hash.
Is there a way to merely test that they are hashes of the same thing, **without** knowing what that thing was?

Comment: I don't think so, but I wouldn't put any money on it.  The salt essentially changes the string.  An intriguing cryptographic question though.

Comment: @delnan: He's asking if a string leaves a unique fingerprint on a hash, even if the salt is different.

Comment: Depends on the length of the original string - for long documents, it should be ok, but SMS or Passwords (everything that's really short, 8-10 chars or so) could be found out (with some computation time).

Comment: @thejh without knowing the salt, it would be infeasable (just by examining the two hashes) to determine even for short values.

Comment: @Jonah Bron in response to the fingerprint question, the point of a solid cryptographic hash is that any small change in the input, the output will be radically different so that nothing about the input can be inferred from the output. If a fingerprint is left by the pre-salted input, the hash function has problems.

Comment: @jball: Yes, that's what I though.  I was just clarifying the question to another comment that was deleted.

Comment: If you could do this, salting passwords would be pointless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The strings become completely unique once the salts are added, and there is no way of reversing a hashed string.

Answer (score 4):

No. You could only do that if the same salt was used.

Comment: +1 for the fastest gun - an addition, this is one of the points of salting, to prevent outsiders from seeing that two hashed values came from the same input.

Comment: Technically, with a cryptographic hash you cannot prove that even two identical hashes using the same salt are from the same plaintext.  For an N bit hash, within (2^N)+1 different inputs, there MUST be at least one collision.  Since there MUST be collisions (where different inputs result in the same hash), you cannot _know_ that a given input is identical to the original input; only that they result in the same hash.